# How to inject environment variables to the build process in Jenkins 0.8?

Tags: jenkins

I am reading karma documentation. This is the paragraph I dont understand:

> First go to the job page and click on configure. Then in the Build
>   Environment sub-section, check the “Inject environment variables to
>   the build process” checkbox.
>   http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/Jenkins-CI.html

I have **configure** menu option. But I cannot find “Inject environment variables to the build process”

How can I inject environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Inject environment variables to the build process" is part of EnvInject plugin. Please verify you have that plugin installed

Comment: Uh, thank you. Is Optional in documentation. But, ... maybe is not XD